# ListPointPlot3D but for Curves and not Surfaces?

Tags: plotting

I would like to create a curve in 3 dimensions that's coming from a list of coordinates. I've looked into some functions to help me do this such as ParametricPlot3D, ListPlot3D, ListPointPlot3D, etc.. However, I haven't actually found anything that does what I need, all of these either take a function as input or give me a surface plot instead of a curve. Does anyone know of another function or some workaround to this?

Comment: `Graphics3D`+`Line`?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like that should work fine. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!